# WebSphere Liberty-18.0.0.4 unable to consume messages from IBM MQ

Tags: websphere, mdb

I have installed WebSphere Liberty 18.0.0.4 and IBM MQ client in my corporate laptop.
I have configured server.xml in such a way that the my localhost can get and put messages in IBM MQ which is running on server. 
I installed my application on WebSphere liberty which can put messages in MQ but however not consuming the message. 
Can you please help how to find where it goes wrong? 
Below is the `server.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="Default server">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>javaee-8.0</feature>
        <feature>ejbPersistentTimer-3.2</feature>
        <!--feature>JDBC-4.1</feature-->
        <!--feature>webProfile-7.0</feature-->
        <feature>wmqJmsClient-2.0</feature>
        <feature>jmsMdb-3.2</feature>
        <feature>jms-2.0</feature>
        <!--feature>jsf-2.2</feature-->
        <!--feature>servlet-3.1</feature-->
        <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
        <!--feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature-->
        <!--feature>restConnector-1.0</feature-->
        <feature>wasJmsServer-1.0</feature>
        <feature>wasJmsClient-2.0</feature>
        <feature>ejbRemote-3.2</feature>
        <feature>ejb-3.2</feature>
        <feature>concurrent-1.0</feature>
        <feature>ejblite-3.2</feature>
        <!--feature>cdi-1.2</feature-->
        <feature>federatedRegistry-1.0</feature>
        <feature>transportSecurity-1.0</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <!--feature>ssl-1.0</feature-->
            <!--feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature-->
             <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
            <feature>jca-1.7</feature>
            <feature>ldapRegistry-3.0</feature>
             <!--feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature-->
            <feature>websocket-1.1</feature>
        <!--feature>beanValidation-1.1</feature-->
    </featureManager>

    <!--For a user registry configuration, configure your user registry. For example, configure a basic user registry using the
        basicRegistry element. Specify your own user name below in the name attribute of the user element. For the password,
        generate an encoded password using bin/securityUtility encode and add it in the password attribute of the user element.
        Then uncomment the user element. -->
    <!--basicRegistry id="basic" realm="BasicRealm"-->
        <!-- <user name="yourUserName" password="" /> 
    </basicRegistry-->
      <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="keyspass" /> 
    <!-- To allow access to this server from a remote client host="*" has been added to the following element -->
    <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  host="*"
                  httpPort="9081"
                  httpsPort="9449" />

    <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>

     <variable name="wmqJmsClient.rar.location" value="C:/Program Files/IBM/MQ/java/lib/jca/wmq.jmsra.rar"/>

    <jmsConnectionFactory jndiName="jms/jmsConnectionFactory">
      <properties.wmqJms maxPoolDepth="10" transportType="CLIENT" hostName="QTQTBI2.nl.eu.abnamro.com" port="1414" channel="ZTAT241.QTQTBI2.03" queueManager="QTQTBI2" />
      <connectionManager maxPoolSize="10" minPoolSize="5" connectionTimeout="360s" maxIdleTime="30m" agedTimeout="30m" reapTime="180s" />
   </jmsConnectionFactory>

  <jmsQueue id="queue/t24OFSQueue" jndiName="queue/t24OFSQueue">
    <properties.wmqJms baseQueueName="API.RUNTIME_REQUEST_ET_FIX.AO" baseQueueManagerName="QTQTBI2" transportType="CLIENT"/>                  
    </jmsQueue>

    <jmsQueue id="queue/t24OFSReplyQueue" jndiName="queue/t24OFSReplyQueue">
     <properties.wmqJms baseQueueName="API.RUNTIME_REQUEST_ET_FIX.AI" baseQueueManagerName="QTQTBI2" transportType="CLIENT"/>                  
    </jmsQueue>


</server>
```

Below is the `SystemOut.log`:

```
[ERROR   ] CWIMK0011E: The user registry operation could not be completed. A valid user registry was not found. Add or correct the registry definition in the server.xml file.
com.ibm.wsspi.security.wim.exception.NoUserRepositoriesFoundException: CWIMK0011E: The user registry operation could not be completed. A valid user registry was not found. Add or correct the registry definition in the server.xml file.
        at com.ibm.ws.security.wim.ProfileManager.genericProfileManagerMethod(ProfileManager.java:223)
        at [internal classes]

2019-07-22 16:26:59 [Default Executor-thread-1281] DEBUG:: >>>> direct://holdings-PSD2.getAccountOverview Exchange[ID-NLLR4000508015-1563804055316-36-3]
2019-07-22 16:26:59 [Default Executor-thread-1281] INFO ::  Request: ENQUIRY.SELECT,,UPGRADEUSER.2/U123456u/BE0010001///,PZ.API.ACCOUNTS.1.0.0,ACCOUNTREFERENCE:EQ=674400057512
2019-07-22 16:26:59 [Default Executor-thread-1281] DEBUG:: response queue used is queue/OFSReplyQueue for client type INTERNAL
[WARNING ] J2CA8501E: Property transportType of configuration element com.ibm.ws.jca.adminObject.supertype[queue/OFSReplyQueue] cannot be set because it is not found on the class com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy.
2019-07-22 16:26:59 [Default Executor-thread-1281] DEBUG:: jms destination lookup successfull forqueue/OFSReplyQueue
2019-07-22 16:26:59 [Default Executor-thread-1281] DEBUG:: request queue used is queue/OFSQueue for client type INTERNAL
[WARNING ] J2CA8501E: Property transportType of configuration element com.ibm.ws.jca.adminObject.supertype[queue/OFSQueue] cannot be set because it is not found on the class com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy.
2019-07-22 16:26:59 [Default Executor-thread-1281] DEBUG:: jms destination lookup successfull forqueue/OFSQueue

2019-07-22 16:27:59 [Default Executor-thread-1281] ERROR:: Response not received from APP for Message Sent with JMS Correlation id e6e081d3-759f-43d9-9ee9-b37bfc2516da
2019-07-22 16:27:59 [Default Executor-thread-1281] ERROR:: JTC-001,Failed to send message to APP via JMS
2019-07-22 16:27:59 [Default Executor-thread-1281] ERROR:: TGVCP-001
2019-07-22 16:27:59 [Default Executor-thread-1281] DEBUG:: Writing response in non-chunked mode as plain text with content-length 129 and buffer size: 4096
```

Can anyone please suggest how I can fix this?

Comment: I may have corrupted your ``SystemOut.log``;  please check and correct as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with MQ name.

The jndiName="queue/t24OFSReplyQueue configuration in server.xml was supposed to be API.RUNTIME_REPLY_ET_FIX.AI whereas I had it configured as API.RUNTIME_REQUEST_ET_FIX.AI.